# What are possible Scalability options for an application supporting ONLY Single TCP Socket Connection?

Tags: scalability, tcpsocket

There is a legacy implementation(to an extent company proprietary in Pascal, C with some java macros) which processes TCP Socket based requests from TCP client application. It supports multiple client applications(around 5K) connecting over TCP Socket, however, it only supports single socket connection with backend(database). There are two instances of the server, so in total, it supports 10K client applications over two TCP Socket connection with database. All database related communication happens in synchronous manner over single socket connection. There are massive issues in this application, especially higher RTT(Round Trip Time) and occasional outages due to back-pressure. We have an ops team for such issues. They mostly resolve them by restarting the server. Hardly, we have people in our team who know coding details of this application and there is not much documentation. As this is a critical application we can not afford messing with it. We don't want to touch the code at least for now. This even becomes more critical due to shift in business priorities. There is a need to add another 30K client applications of another business with this setup.

Task before us is to integrate it with another application which is based on microservice architecture with middleware using RabbitMQ. This is a customer facing application sensitive to higher QoS. We can not afford outage & downtime in it. As part of this integration, there is a need to process request messages coming from the above legacy application over TCP Socket before passing them to database. In other words, we want to introduce a component which would process requests of legacy application before handing over to database. This additional process is part of our client request. Some of the processing requirement is very intensive and resource hungry in terms of CPU Cycle, Memory and socket i/o. As a result, there are chances, such processing may lead to server downtime & higher RTT. Our this layer is very flexible, we can easily add more server or replace faulty ones. But, this doesn't sound very efficient in this integration as we are limited with single socket connection of legacy application. So in total at max, we can only have 2(+ 6 for new 30k client application) servers. This is our cause of concern.

I want know, what different possible options are available to address high availability, scalability and latency issues of such integration? Especially with limitation of single TCP socket connection, how can we make this integration efficient, something which can handle back-pressure, better application uptime etc.

We were thinking of leveraging RabbitMQ, Layer 4 Load balancer(like haProxy, NginX), IPVS, NAT etc.. But all lead toward making some changes(or not very efficient technique) in the legacy code, which we don't want.

Comment: If you don't want to change the implementation, only scalability move I can see is increasing number of instances of your legacy service. Because as far as I understand number of database connections will be always a bottleneck for you.

Comment: thanks for inputs, yes, that's what we are also thinking of.